# If the quotientspace $=^+$ is linearly orderable then why has the graph $Z$ chromatic number $2$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This is Observation 3.23 from ''Canonical models for fragments of the Axiom of Choice'' from Paul Larson and Jindrich Zapletal.

We define the equivalence relation $=^+$ as follows: It connects $x,y\in X=(2^\omega)^\omega$ iff $rng(x)=rng(y)$. The graph $Z$ connects $x,y\in X$ if $\{x(n):n\in\omega\}=\{1-y(n):n\in\omega\}$ holds and $x=^+y$ fails.

Now let $\leq$ be a linear order on the $=^+$ quotient space. Define the function $c$ by letting $c(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{for all } y\in X\text{ with }xZy\text{, }[y]_{=^+}<[x]_{=^+}\text{ holds,}\\
1, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$

for $x\in X$. Now it is claimed that it is not difficult to see that $c$ is a coloring of $Z$. Well but somehow I don't get to see it; so why is it so? Thanks for answering!

Comment: What is $1-x(n)$ if $x(n)\in 2^\omega$? Do you mean it's the complement sequence?

Comment: I suppose so. It neighter is explained in the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x\mathrel{Z}y$, if both have the same color, then it can't be $0$, so it must be $1$. Suppose also that $[y]_{=^+}<[x]_{=^+}$.

Now, $x$ itself is already a witness that $c(y)=1$, so there must be some $z$ such that $x\mathrel{Z}z$, but $[x]_{=^+}<[z]_{=^+}$.

But what does that mean?

Well, first of all it means that $\{1-y(n)\mid n\in\omega\}=\{x(n)\mid n\in\omega\}=\{1-z(n)\mid n\in\omega\}$. But that means that $y=^+z$, so $[y]_{=^+}=[z]_{=^+}$. But that's impossible, since this means $[y]_{=^+}<[x]_{=^+}<[z]_{=^+}=[y]_{=^+}$.